# Accessing web-server in private network from arbitrary clients

Tags: http, proxy, mjpeg, webproxy

I am looking for the best practice to allow accessing a web-server in a private network from a client running on an arbitrary machine (possibly on another private network). Here is the typical setup:

- Web-server is running on a Linux machine behind NAT (not directly accessible by the client) and is being used for JPEG streaming.
- Client my run on any device and cannot be directly accessed by the web-server.
- An intermediate server (Linux machine) which can be directly accessed by both the web-server and clients (since it owns a static IP address).

The first solution that comes to my mind is using the intermediate server as a web proxy and creating a SSH tunnel between the intermediate machine and the web-server, however it requires clients to make changes to their proxy settings which is not an option in my case. The other solution which would possibly work is having the intermediate machine to forward HTTP requests to the web-server, though I do not know of any easy way to do so. Since it looks like a common case to me, I feel like there should be some service which does that. I am also open to other solutions which would offer transparent access to the web-server.

Comment: Can you not simply port-forward the web server through the NAT to make it accessible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the network device (router/switch) which is facing the public network since the streaming server can be plugged to any local network. The streaming server is basically a SoC board which is connected to a WiFi network.